# Scroll slowly to bottom of page?

Tags: javascript

Very new to Javascript, The purpose to scroll slowly to the bottom of the page is to load the entire page of search results. Once the entire page is loaded I have code to retrieve the links of the search results. Secondary Question: Is there any other way to load the page besides scrolling?

I found code that automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page the middle part of the page doesn't load when you do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: originally said java, meant javascript

also note: I have 0 Programming Experience, didn't write this, just frankensteined pieces together. Just trying to get this last piece of code to work for a project and then I'm done doing any javascript until I sit down and actually take a course on it.

This is the full code. Also will have to implement a pause after the scroll to wait for the results to load.

```
window.scrollTo({ top:document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth', })

///pause here

try {

  var maxLinks = 25;  
  var returnData = "URL";  
  var xPath = '//*[@class="r"]/a';

  var xpathResults = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, 0, null);

  var oNode = xpathResults.iterateNext();

  var nodeList = [];
  var linkCount = 0;
  var hrefStr;
  var returnStr;
  var linkText;

  while (oNode && (linkCount < maxLinks)) {

    if (oNode.href !== hrefStr) {
      linkCount += 1;
      hrefStr = oNode.href;
      linkText = oNode.textContent;

      if (returnData === "MD") {
        returnStr = "[" + linkText + "](" + hrefStr + ")";
      }
      else {
        returnStr = hrefStr;
      }

      nodeList.push(returnStr);
    }

    oNode = xpathResults.iterateNext();

  } 

  returnResults = nodeList.join('\n');


} catch (pError) {

    if (!oError.message) {
      oError.message = pError.toString();
    }

    oError.message = "[ERROR]"
      + "\n\nError Number: " + oError.errorNumber + "\n"
      + oError.message

    returnResults = oError.message;  
} 

function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.value = text;
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
copyToClipboard(returnResults)
copyToClipboard(returnResults)
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Your description and tags don't match. Also, if you could please provide us with some code and explain the issue/problem you are trying to overcome with it that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're taking about scraping using java and selenium, then don't scroll to end. Just scroll upto page height (ex: `scrollTo(0, window.innerHeight)`) get links and again scroll and get links keep doing until you reach page end.

Comment: @MattDavis Added additional context and code in the post, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you mean Java or Javascript but in Javascript, You can use:

```js
window.scrollTo({ top:document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth', })
```

It will scroll to bottom of the page with a smooth effect.

Comment: is there anyway to go slower than this? it loaded 2/3 of the results but not all of them?